# Change all timestamps with certain time of day to previous date

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to convert all rows of data where the timestamp has a time of 05:59:59 AM or below to the previous date. So for example '2018-12-08 05:05:00' would be '2018-12-07' and '2018-11-06 03:02:00' would be '2018-11-05'.

Timestamps are in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and are stored as varchar

Here's my stab at a query so far:

```
SELECT lift.spot_datetime AS broadcastdate,
    CASE when broadcastdate > to_date(>='06:00:00', 'hh:mm:ss') then to_date('MM/DD/YYYY') end as same_date,
    ELSE when broadcastdate > to_date(<='05:59:59', 'hh:mm:ss') then DATE_SUB(to_date('MM/DD/YYYY' - 1) end as subtract_date
```

An issue I've encountered is that it seems that the AWS Athena client I'm running queries through don't seem to be able to resolve the "dateadd" or "datesub" functions.

"An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:17: Column 'day' cannot be resolved"

The current error I get when I run the above query is as follows:
"An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. line 2:39: no viable alternative at input 'to_date(>=' [Execution ID not available]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your SQL query, it's not really clear what kind of result structure you want, but let me give it a shot:

```sql
SELECT
    spot_datetime AS broadcastdate,
    IF ( TIME(spot_datetime) < '06:00:00',
        DATE(spot_datetime) - INTERVAL 1 DAY,
        DATE(spot_datetime)
    ) AS your_desired_date
FROM lift;
```

```
+---------------------+-------------------+
| broadcastdate       | your_desired_date |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| 2018-12-08 05:05:00 | 2018-12-07        |
| 2018-11-06 03:02:00 | 2018-11-05        |
| 2018-11-06 06:00:00 | 2018-11-06        |
+---------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That format would work, but unfortunately I'm still getting an error from the AWS Athena client:           



"[HY000][100071] [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Queries of this type are not supported [Execution ID not available]"

Comment: I've just exported the data to a MySQL Workbench so I can run the query properly, but I would like to now change the dates so that if the timestamp does not contain info for "HH:MM:SS", it is also flagged as residing on the same date, and returned in the "your_desired_date" column. How would I be able to do so?

Comment: Replace the `IF` line with the following: `IF ( LENGTH(spot_datetime) > 11 AND TIME(spot_datetime) < '06:00:00',`

Comment: Was able to get the query to run, but there's still many values that return NULL values. Additionally, many correctly formatted datetime stamps are returning NULL values for the converted dates as well, e.g. 4/15/2019 8:18:00 returns NULL and 4/9/2019 10:20:00 returns NULL.

I've tried reimporting the csv data into a sql file with spot_datetime as a datetime value, using a query to convert the column to datetime, and then running the query, but that yields spot_datetime as NULL too. Any ideas for how I could resolve all these NULL values?

Comment: Never mind, found it's easier to just manually filter for NULL values in Excel and update cell values with the correct values using a formula

Comment: From MySQL point of view, `4/15/2019 8:18:00` is not a correctly formatted datetime stamp, that's why such timestamps yield `NULL`. To handle custom datetime formats you can use `str_to_date()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). You could convert such timestamps to standard format like this: `update lift set spot_datetime=ifnull(str_to_date(spot_datetime, '%c/%e/%Y %T'), spot_datetime)`. But I'm glad you managed to solve the problem with Excel.

Comment: In the meantime, if you found my help useful, please consider marking the answer as correct. Thank you.